# How can python do imports after I clear sys.path - Import precedence

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, python-import

I have a python module named Queue that conflicts with the default queue in python.

While trying to force the import of the default queue, I tried to simply clear sys.path.

I was of the understanding that the imports are looked up from sys.path.
But Python still seems to be able to import modules after I clear syspath.

Explain this please!

```
In [26]: sys.path
Out[26]: []
In [27]: import datetime
In [28]: datetime
Out[28]: <module 'datetime' from '/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so'>
In [31]: import xyz.Queue
In [32]: xyz.Queue
Out[32]: <module 'xyz.Queue' from '/public/abc/def/ghi/xyz/Queue/__init__.pyc'>
In [33]: sys.path
Out[33]: []
```

Also How to import native module queue instead of Queue.

I know that refactoring Queue is the solution this problem deserves, but it not the one it needs right now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in the default python shell, but I can reproduce it in IPython. There are several questions commenting on the unusual behavior of sys.path in IPython. Hopefully adding the tag will clue someone in.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using CentOS and I typed this out in Django Shell.

Answer (score 1):

Add `from __future__ import absolute_import` as the first line in your file.

This will force all imports to be absolute rather then relative. So `import Queue` will import the standard module, to import a local module you'd use `from . import foobar`

Comment: Explicit relative imports only work if you're in a package. If the user's `Queue` package is in the same folder as the script that is being run, that won't help. Moving the `Queue.py` file into a package, however, is probably a good solution.

Comment: Tried that. No avail. I am running this in a django app - so let me know if that is an issue.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the script is running from folder xyz and Queue is in xyz. So I guess there is no point in absolute_import right?

Comment: This isn't answering the question of why modules can still be loaded if sys.path is empty. Answer is probably because the internals use another symbol to hold the path, and sys.path is just a shallow copy of it. But, would have to check the Python internals for that.